# How to fix broken alphabet in binary image

Tags: opencv

I have one picture.

[image: Original picture]

There are many broken places in the image.

Please refer to the the picture.

[image: Picture with broken places]

Who knows how to repair the broken stroke using opencv 3.0?

I used dilate operation in OpenCV and I got the picture as belows:

[image: Dilation result]

It looks so ugly if comparing the original image.

Comment: Dilation works depending on the kernel structure, kernel size and number of iterations. What did you choose?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I choose:     Mat element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_CROSS, Size(3, 5), Point(-1, -1));

Comment: I hope the final repaired image looks the same as the original image, just fix the broken part. After I do the dilation, the alphabet in the image looks so fat, it is not so easy to be read.

Comment: try erosion after that. Use an ellipse kernel

Comment: I tried, it looks more ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I am late to the party but I hope this helps someone.

Since you have not provided the original image I cannot say the following solution would work 100%. Not sure how you are thresholding the image but adaptive thresholding might give you better results. Opencv (Python) code:

```
gauss_win_size = 5
gauss_sigma = 3
th_window_size = 15
th_offset = 2

img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(gauss_win_size,gauss_win_size),gauss_sigma)
th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img_blur,255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,th_window_size,th_offset)
```

Tinker around with the parameter values to see what values work best. It's usually a good idea to blur your image and that might possibly take care of broken binary images of alphabets. Note, blurring may eventually produce slightly thicker characters in the binary image. If this still leaves with a few broken characters then you can use morphological closing:

```
selem_shape = cv2.MORPH_RECT
selem_size = (3, 3)

selem = cv2.getStructuringElement(selem_shape, selem_size)
th = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, selem)
```

Again, tinker around with structuring element size and shape that works best with your images.